# Using a Join then Expression in ModelBuilder, no data coming up?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

Have a model that converts an excel table to a geodatabase table and converts a shapefile to a layer.  Then joins the geodatabase table and layer together.  After the join I want to create a new layer with specific attributes using an expression.  However when I click on "get values" to build my expression, no data for any of the fields comes up.

Wondering if I'm missing a step after the join?  Or if ModelBuilder doesn't let you select attributes since the join hasn't actually happened yet?

[image]

Comment: does your join rely on the field calculation ? Maybe you have to type your expression without the get value because the values possibly change in your workflow

Comment: Big time thanks radouxju.  My join did rely on a field calculation and concatenated the field names.  I was originally using the concatenated field names in my expression.  When I Used the original field name with the expression it worked.  Was a little thrown off becuase when I tried to verify the expression it said there was an "error", must have something to do with the join.